# Table view cell checkmark changes position when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I am new to Swift. I have created a simple list in a tableview. When the user long presses on a row, that row will get checked. It's working perfectly fine. But when I scroll down, check mark changes its position. I also tried to store position in NSMutableSet. But still it's not working. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

This is my code:

This method gets called on long press.

```
func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    let longpress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    let state = longpress.state
    let locationInview = longpress.location(in: tableview1)
    var indexpath=tableview1.indexPathForRow(at: locationInview)

    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began)
    {
        if(tableview1.cellForRow(at: indexpath!)?.accessoryType == 
        UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark)
        {
            tableview1.cellForRow(at: indexpath!)?.accessoryType = 
                UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        else{
            tableview1.cellForRow(at: indexpath!)?.accessoryType = 
                UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want me to help you with the formatting? Also this will crash if you long press where there is no cell, I can fix that for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that cells are reused and when you update a checkmark, you're updating a cell, but not updating your model. So when a cell scrolls out of view and the cell is reused, your `cellForRowAt` is obviously not resetting the checkmark for the new row of the table.

Likewise, if you scroll the cell back into view, `cellForRowAt` has no way of knowing whether the cell should be checked or not. You have to

- when you detect your gesture on the cell, you have to update your model to know that this row's cell should have a check; and
- your `cellForRowAt` has to look at this property when configuring the cell.

So, first make sure your model has some value to indicate whether it is checked/selected or not. In this example, I'll use "Item", but you'd use a more meaningful type name:

```
struct Item {
    let name: String
    var checked: Bool
}
```

Then your view controller can populate cells appropriately in `cellForRowAt`:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var items: [Item]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addItems()
    }

    /// Create a lot of sample data so I have enough for a scrolling view

    private func addItems() {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        items = (0 ..< 1000).map { Item(name: formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0))!, checked: false) }
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].name
        cell.accessoryType = items[indexPath.row].checked ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
}
```

Now, I generally let the cell handle stuff like recognizing gestures and inform the view controller accordingly. So create a `UITableViewCell` subclass, and specify this as the base class in the cell prototype on the storyboard. But the cell needs some protocol to inform the view controller that a long press took place:

```
protocol ItemCellDelegate: class {
    func didLongPressCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

And the table view controller can handle this delegate method, toggling its model and reloading the cell accordingly:

```
extension ViewController: ItemCellDelegate {
    func didLongPressCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

        items[indexPath.row].checked = !items[indexPath.row].checked
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Then, the `UITableViewCell` subclass just needs a long press gesture recognizer and, upon the gesture being recognized, inform the view controller:

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }

    @IBAction func handleLongPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began {
            delegate?.didLongPressCell(self)
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, by having the gesture on the cell, it avoids confusion resulting from "what if I long press on something that isn't a cell". The cell is the right place for the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the change anywhere.

To avoid using too much memory, the phone reuses cells and asks you to configure them in the `TableView`'s `dataSource`.

Let's say you have an array called `data` that has some structs that store what you want to show as cells. You would need to update this array and tell the tableView to reload your cell.

```
func userDidLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    // We only care if the user began the longPress
    guard gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began else {
        return
    }

    let locationInView = gestureRecognizer.location(in: tableView)

    // Nothing to do here if user didn't longPress on a cell
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: locationInView) else {
        return
    }

    // Flip the associated value and reload the row
    data[indexPath.row].isChecked = !data[indexPath.row].isChecked
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

And always set the accessory when you configure a cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: "someIdentifier",
        for: indexPath
    )

    cell.accessoryType = data[indexPath.row].isChecked ? .checkmark : .none
}
```